# Save image cache on CDN or turn image cache off

Tags: magento-1.8, cache

I'm using Cloud Files CDN to host media and skin folders, and it's working properly for images and files located on that CDN. But the issue i'm having is with cached images. Every time new image cache is generated in media/catalog/products folder it is not displayed on front-end. Obviously it's because the cached image does not exist on CDN.

Is there any way to force magento to save cache on CDN? Or turn off image cache?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a problem with the CDN implementation itself.

You may want to consider going with a HTTP Pull type of CDN which will cache even newly generated files as soon as they are accessed for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In whatever manner you populate the CDN, write a cron job script that periodically scans for new files and pushes them, or if you have simpler access than that, use `rsync` to replicate everything over. You don't need to mess with Magento to do this.

The easiest is to just use an `Origin Pull CDN` which automatically takes care of this, or check in your current CDN to see if it already does "Origin Pull" and finish out setting it up.

Because of the auto-resizing and structured storage, turning off Magento's image cache isn't really an option.